# How can i calculate the probability of Timeseries DataFrame?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on Timeseries DataFrame. Here i have Historical data of XAUUSD

```
            Date     Open     High      Low    Close
5008  2018-03-28  1345.66  1347.26  1323.94  1326.53
5009  2018-03-29  1326.81  1328.48  1322.02  1325.36
5010  2018-04-02  1326.91  1345.06  1326.13  1342.05
5011  2018-04-03  1341.86  1342.54  1329.53  1333.57
5012  2018-04-04  1333.48  1344.28  1331.77  1343.31
```

What i am trying to do is not to predict the next day's prices. I am trying to get probability list (%) of next days prices.

For example "How much can High value be maximum and minimum?" or "How much can Low value be?" including %. Let's say it can increate between 1.0001% - 1.015%

I am not sure which model to use. I have used LinearRegression but it is only to predict prices. So here is what i am need from the model:

```
1. Train the past data
2. Get how much High away from yesterday's Close price (min/max)
3. Get how much High away from yesterday's Low price (min/max)
4. Sort values and show me all probabilities
```

Do you think this is possible with any sklearn models?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is either a confidence interval from a frequentist model, or the posterior mean and variance from a Bayesian model.

For your case, you can use a Gaussian Process to get your posterior. What it means is that instead of predicting a single value, which would be your expected mean, it also gives you a variance of the posterior, which you can use to see how *confident* the model is to predict the outcome.

Fitting those models on a one dimensional data (low or high in your case) is pretty straightforward and you can visualize them nicely like the ones you see [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/notebook/blob/master/GPy/basic_gp.ipynb).

[image]

My favourite Gaussian Process implementation is [GPy](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy/), but you can use whichever you like.

I applied the same concept for a different problem which you can read on [here](http://adrin.info/tv-ad-attribution-gaussian-processes.html).

Comment: thank you very much. Tutorial looks great. I will take a look and try to apply it my end. I actually manually predict the statistics. This is the way i follow: I am getting last 30 days open high low close prices. And generate stats using this technique. I am getting the movement percent from open-low, high-low, low-low, close-low and same for high. The smallest amounts are the maximum range of the tomorrow's prices. So the model should bring me this saying 75% will be between 1350-1354 etc.